# Advanced Installer Mystery File/Folders

Tags: installation, advanced-installer

Using Advanced Installer. When I build and run my install project, after the install there is a folder called `MyCompany` (equivalent to `[Manufacturer]`) located within the `ApplicationData` folder (which resolves to `C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Roaming\` on my system).

Within that particular folder is another folder called `MyProgram 1.0.0` (equivalent to `[ProductName] [ProductVersion]`.

And within that folder is another folder called `install`. And within that folder is a file called `setup.msi` with a size of 1.17MB

I have no understanding of why this file and these folders are being created. Further, after I uninstall my app, they get left behind on the system, which means my app is creating garbage.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? And also...if I can't cause this to not be present in the file system while my app is installed, how can I avoid leaving it behind on the file system after I uninstall?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the size of the original msi also 1.17 MB?

Comment: No it is definitely something different. I'm building an EXE installer anyways, and the file size of that is about 50MB

Answer (score 1):

When you are building an EXE setup file, that is the default extraction folder for the EXE, where you can find all the resources during the installation. You can change it from Media page, "Extraction folder".

It is not deleted after uninstall due a bug in Advanced Installer, you can [find more details and a workaround on the forums](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=23179#p60094).